# distributing n different balls into r numbered cells

Tags: probability

> We distribute 5 different balls into 3 numbered cells
>
> All the different distributions have equal probability

I am trying to find all the possible probabilities of empty cells but I get some weird results
**[the point in this exercise is to find Var(Y)**]:

Let Y be the number of the empty cells.

$P(Y=0)=1-P(Y=1)-P(Y=2)-P(Y=3)$
$P(Y=1)=3*\frac{2^5}{3^5}$
$P(Y=2)=3*\frac{2^5}{3^5}$    [this part is probably wrong]
$P(Y=3)=0$

My problem is that the chance that all the cells are empty must be 0 I think because we distribute the balls into the cells so at least 1 cell got a ball

But I get weird results I need to calculate the variance of Y but with these chances I get that
$Var(Y)=0.722$
This is wrong.

---

If I look at this problem like a binomial distribution problem:
Lets remember that the chance of a given cell to be empty is $(\frac{2}{3})^5=0.1316$

$Y$~$B(3, (\frac{2}{3})^5)$

So $Var(Y)=np(1-p)=0.34$

This is wrong too **AND** it is different from the first part which is even worse :(

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Why is $p(Y=2)=3\cdot\frac{2^5}{3^5}$? If two cells are empty ($Y=2$) then all 5 balls have to go into a single cell so $\frac{1}{3^4}$.

Comment: @almagest it makes sense I just did the normal method of "all the ways to select 2 cells" mutliplied by the chance of a given cell to be empty" but you are right I think I'm missing here something with my "chance of a cell to be empty" which I used everywhere but why $\frac{1}{3^4}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y_{i}$ take value $1$ if cell $i$ stays empty and let it take
value $0$ otherwise.

Then $Y=Y_{1}+Y_{2}+Y_{3}$.

The $Y_{i}$ have
equal distribution but are not independent.

With linearity of expectation
and symmetry we find:

$\mathbb{E}Y=3\mathbb{E}Y_{1}=3\mathbb{P}\left(Y_{1}=1\right)$

$\mathbb{E}Y^{2}=3\mathbb{E}Y_{1}^{2}+6\mathbb{E}Y_{1}Y_{2}=3\mathbb{P}\left(Y_{1}=1\right)+6\mathbb{P}\left(Y_{1}=1=Y_{2}\right)$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: What does the special $E$ means? it symbols the expected value? if so how did you make those 2 equations?

Comment: It means expected value, yes. If $Y=Y_1+Y_2+Y_3$ then linearity of independence tells us that $EY=EY_1+EY_2+EY_3$. This with $EY_1=EY_2=EY_3$ so $EY=3EY_1$ (i.e. applying symmetry). The second comes from working out $Y^2=(Y_1+Y_2+Y_3)^2$ and then again taking expectation on both sides, followed again by application of symmetry.

Comment: You can of course go searching for the distribution of $Y$ (as you did) but this is an alternative route, showing that that is not necessary. It is handsome and elegant and will not be bothered by higher values of $n$ and $r$. This in contrast with the method that goes after the distribution.

Comment: Oh I see, for me its harder because I'm more used to the normal methods so I'm having hard time understanding this